# Call method when clicking on a link in PageObject

Tags: watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I am using Watir-Webdriver along with the PageObject gem to automate tests.

I have a PageObject defined like this:

```
class Page
  include PageObject

  div(:loading_indicator, :class => 'loading_indicator')

  div(:display_detail, :id => 'log_module_detail')

  # large number of links like this:
  link(:input1) { display_detail_element.link_element(:id => 'detailed_input1') }
  link(:input2) { display_detail_element.link_element(:id => 'detailed_input2') }
  # input3, input4, etc.. 

  def wait_on_loading_indicator
    loading_indicator_element.when_not_present # wait till loading indicator is gone
  end
end
```

When I press `input1` the `loading_indicator` becomes present and I want to wait for it to disappear before continuing.

Of course I could just define a method like this:

```
def click_input1
  input1
  wait_on_loading_indicator
end
```

But then I would have to define a method like that for every link...
Ideally I would want something like this:
`link(:input1) { display_detail_element.link_element(:id => 'detailed_input1'); wait_on_loading_indicator }`
But that doesn't work. Is there some easy/clean way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to create an accessor that defines the normal link methods and override the click method to also call the `wait_on_loading_indicator` method.

The page object would be:

```
class MyPage
  include PageObject

  def self.detailed_input(name, identifier={:index => 0}, &block)
    link(name, identifier, &block)
    define_method(name) do
      send("#{name}_element").click      
      wait_on_loading_indicator    
    end
  end

  div(:loading_indicator, :class => 'loading_indicator')
  div(:display_detail, :id => 'log_module_detail')

  detailed_input(:input1) { display_detail_element.link_element(:id => 'detailed_input1') }
  detailed_input(:input2) { display_detail_element.link_element(:id => 'detailed_input2') }

  def wait_on_loading_indicator
    loading_indicator_element.when_not_present
  end  
end
```

Notice that the `detailed_input` class method:
1. Calls the standard `link` accessor method to setup the standard link methods.
2. Redefines the method that clicks the link to also call the `wait_on_loading_indicator` method.

Links that need to wait for the indicator would use the custom accessor method rather than standard `link` method. In other words, they are declared as:

```
detailed_input(:input1) { display_detail_element.link_element(:id => 'detailed_input1') }
detailed_input(:input2) { display_detail_element.link_element(:id => 'detailed_input2') }
```

You can see this work in the page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>wait test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      function loading() {
        var e = document.getElementById("loading")
        e.style.display = "block";
        setTimeout(function() {
          e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
        }, 2000);
      }        
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="loading" class="loading_indicator" style="display:none;">loading</div>
    <div id="log_module_detail">
      <a href="#" id="detailed_input1" onclick="loading();">detailed_input1</a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When the following code is run against the page object:

```
page = MyPage.new(browser)
puts page.loading_indicator_element.visible?
#=> false
page.input1
puts page.loading_indicator_element.visible?
#=> false (this would return `true` without the wait method)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for and allows me to keep my code DRY. Thanks!